# return ListItemAllFields on a previous file version

Tags: versioning, list-item

I am trying to retrieve ListItemAllFields for a previous version of  a file in a Document Library

```
foreach (FileVersion version in listItem.File.Versions)
        {
string versionItemUrl = listItem.File.ServerRelativeUrl.Replace(Path.GetFileName(listItem.File.ServerRelativeUrl), "") + version.Url;
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File oldFile = 
web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(versionItemUrl);
var allFields = oldFile.ListItemAllFields;
clientContext.Load(oldFile, f => f.ListItemAllFields);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();}
```

Everything works fine up to this point, but all properties in ListItemAllFields come up as not initialized. Basically the listItem returns empty